# uint8_t conversion to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to convert the contents of a single element in my uint8_t buffer to an NSString so that I can display it to a label on my iPhone app.  I read in the contents of buffer OK from a TCP connection.  I am not getting the proper encoding so that an element's value can be displayed correctly.  For example, if buffer[4] has the contents of 0xFD or 253, how do I best get that transferred to the label?  (The label is data1)  Or is there a much simpler way?  Thanks.

```
uint8_t buffer[64]; 
uint8_t tinybuffer[1];
int len;

// Read in contents from TCP connection, log dump, and display to label.
len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];

if (len > 0) {
// Log dump
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Returning byte %d  : %x", i, buffer[i]);
}
NSLog(@"Finished Reading");

// Get data to the screen.
tinybuffer[0] = buffer[4];
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:tinybuffer length:1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
_data1.text = str1;
```

Comment: What character should be displayed for the 0xFD byte?

Comment: I am using buffer for Modbus transmissions.  I need to pluck out elements of the array and display them.  The 0xFD needs to be displayed as 253 as it's numerical converted value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tinybuffer[0]];
```

should do what you want.

Comment: OK. Just did that.  I'm new to posting to this site.  Thanks.

Comment: It's %s now instead of %d

Comment: No. %s is for C strings. %d is for integers.